# Segmentation fault during calculation of RMS

Tags: c++, qt, math

I have the following code:

```
float am::getMA()
{
    double cVA = 0;
    double pS = 0;
    double avg = 0;

    const qint16 *ampliData = audioGather().constData<qint16>();
    double sampleCount = audioGather().sampleCount();

    for (int i=0; i<sampleCount; i++){
        avg = ampliData[i]/peak;
        pS += avg * avg;
        count++;
    }
    cVA = sqrt(pS / (sampleCount/2));
    return cVA;
}
```

This runs every 1 second and updates a label with the value.  For the first 5 seconds or so of runtime (so, five calls of the function), it's fine.  But after that, the app crashes with a segfault at line `avg = ampliData[i]/peak;`

The debugger isn't providing any helpful information and all the variable values at the breakpoint seem fine.

Here is `audioGather()`:

```
QAudioBuffer am::audioGather()
{
    QAudioFormat format;
    format.setSampleRate(40000);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleFormat(QAudioFormat::Int16);
    QByteArray sA = UC::getSigned16();
    QAudioBuffer ampliBuffer(sA, format, -1);

    return ampliBuffer;
}
```

Further, `UC::getSigned16()` is simply grabbing a value from a different function which doesn't clear the previous value until a new one is loaded, so there shouldn't (and hasn't) been a condition where it's empty.

Comment: Typically when you crash during division, it's because the denominator is 0.

Comment: But it could also be because you might be accessing memory outside of what's allocated for ampliData. There's no way for us to know from what you've shown.

Comment: What does audioGather() returns? I would guess it's a temporary and therefore you're probably working on invalid data.

Comment: Could you split that line into two to know if the division or the access is the cause of the problem? 
`const auto& data = ampliData[i];` and then `avg = data/peak` ? 
What is the type of `peak`? Also, try to provide an minimum working example.

Comment: Just added audioGather() to the above question.  `peak` is a double.

Comment: The `QAudioBuffer` you return is destroyed after that line, leaving you with an invalid pointer. Also, the next call returns a different object, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: So, I moved the entirety of `audioGather` into `getMA` and it works fine now... I'm not sure I understand why

Answer (score -1):

Given the code snippet you supplied, here are some potential culprits:

- ampliData may not be as big as you think (i.e. less than sampleCount). If that is the case then accessing ampliData[i] may segfault if i > than the actual size of ampliData.
- peak is not defined in the function and might be zero. You mentioned that setting a breakpoint in this code showed that all variables appear to be valid, so this may not be the problem.

My gut says the problem is with the size of the array pointed to by ampliData. You might try setting a breakpoint then viewing the memory pointed to by ampliData.

Comment: > "edited 34 mins ago" "answered 20 mins ago" "original poster added the definition of audioGather() AFTER my post"

Doubt